# debug print not happening sequentially

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the code below, I noted a anomaly which puzzles me. The print string "entryname" gets executed before "somestr" print string. Might I know why this happens?

```
var somestr = "";
con.query(
  'SELECT name,areaid, panellabel,voltageid,installationtypeid from installation, (SELECT companyid from building where name="' +
    req.body.location +
    '")as company where installation.id=company.companyid',
  function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var output = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rows));
    var arr = [];
    console.log(rows);
    output.forEach(function(entry) {
      console.log("entryname is " + entry.name);
      somestr =
        somestr +
        "<TR><TD>" +
        entry.name +
        "<TD>" +
        entry.areaid +
        "<TD>" +
        entry.areaid +
        "<TD>" +
        entry.panellabel +
        "<TD>" +
        "<TD>" +
        entry.voltageid +
        "<TD>" +
        entry.installationtypeid;
      console.log(somestr);
    });
  }
);
console.log("somestr is " + somestr + "end somestr");
tablehead = tablehead + somestr;
console.log(somestr);
res.send(tablehead);
```

Comment: You need to first understand the `async` nature of `node.js`.

Comment: You have an SQL injection vulnerability in the query code.

Comment: Retrieving the value in the callback function would solve my problem as I understand it.

Comment: @AKX, Thanks for pointing out the SQL injection vulnerability. I will be using parameterized query to fix them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NodeJs is Aysnc in nature, if a Async task is executing NodeJS will push that code to stack and executes next available statement.

Same thing is also happening here ..

```
con.query('SELECT name,areaid, panellabel,voltageid,installationtypeid from installation, (SELECT companyid from building where name=\"' + req.body.location + '\")as company where installation.id=company.companyid', function (err, rows, fields) {
  ///
});
```

As this section is doing db I/O NodeJs is pushing this to stack and executing next statement `console.log("somestr is " + somestr + "end somestr");`

and now when the db call is completed it will execute the corresponding block. `console.log('entryname is ' + entry.name);`